# How to fix this sentence without adding more words?

Tags: grammaticality

"In recognition for being a great host, sharing experience in X."

I think it's supposed to be "In recognition for being a great host and sharing their experience in X."

But if I'm not allowed to add more words, would the original sentence still kinda make sense?

Comment: That's a prepositional phrase, not a sentence.

Comment: It is not a complete sentence.

Comment: Not sure if the author has something in mind like, "In recognition of being a great host, he/she will be sharing his/her experiences in ....."

Comment: Who says you are not allowed to add words?

Comment: I've voted to close.  Details are needed - Why "without adding words" What does "fix" mean.  It's all very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

So both sentences are okay, but the first one should be ""In recognition for being a great host, sharing experience in X*,*"—with it ending with a comma, as you will add on more to the sentence. For future reference, add context to your post; I am not sure what "X" is.

Comment: I myself am still new; sorry for the "*" around the comma, it was supposed to be italicized.